# How do I include greek letter in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and gnuplot-x11, and found that for greek letter alpha,

{/symbol a} will work, but that just shows me {/symbol a}, not greek letter alpha.

I tried {\symbol a} or other options, but that does not work..

Comment: Use `set termoption enhanced`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using the syntax `{/Symbol a}` requires that you enable the `enhanced` mode. This can be done in several ways:

1. When setting the terminal

   ```
   set terminal ... enhanced
   ```
2. After setting the terminal with

   ```
   set termoption enhanced
   ```
3. Explicitely for a single label

   ```
   set xlabel '{/Symbol a}' enhanced
   ```

Depending on the output terminal you are using, the best option is to use utf-8 encoding and directly input the characters:

```
set encoding utf8
set xlabel 'α'
```

Comment: Hi, do you have a link to the complete list of greek symbols accessible through `\Symbol`?

Comment: @solalito Gnuplot distributes a document [docs/psdoc/ps_guide.ps](http://gnuplot.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gnuplot/gnuplot/docs/psdoc/ps_guide.ps) which contains these informations.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning UTF-8, it's not that obvious to remember these!

Answer (score 3):

After using enhanced mode, take care for using {/Symbol a}, you have used {/symbol a}, small letter of "s" in Symbol, so you were not getting greek letter alpha.