# How to show π symbol on x axis?

Tags: gnuplot, symbols

Feel frustrated when I cannot add a simple "π" symbol on x axis. I searched lots of solution and there is what I use:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced
set output "test.eps"
set xrange [-2*pi:2*pi]
set sample 600
set xtics pi
set mxtics 2
set xtics ("-2{/Symbol P}" -2*pi, "-{/Symbol P}" -pi, "0" 0, "{/Symbol P}" pi, "2{/Symbol P}" 2*pi)
```

There is no "π" on the x axis! Am I wrong with any codes? or I missed any possible packages? Please see the xlabel below:

[image]

Update: I tried lots of methods including set terminal enhanced, but still doesn't work. And I just find that my mac Preview (pdf viewer) doesnt show character correctly (pic below). I believe that's the reason and I m still working on it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WQzW.jpg)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24653552/2604213

Comment: Thank you @Christoph. Your answer should be a right one, but still not work on my laptop. I kind of know the reason.. I just find that my laptop cannot show some characters correctly! (The document included in your post docs/psdoc/ps_guide.ps)

Comment: Try using a postscript viewer! I wouldn't trust a pdf viewer to show postscript directly. Or generate directly pdf files with the pdfcairo terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I experience the same problem and found a workaround. If I open the resulting eps file from gnuplot in Inkscape and save it as eps file again, the pi character renders as it should. I just use the basic import, not the Poppler, but it's worthy experimenting with both. If I then open the new eps file with Preview, the pi characters are there.