# Greek letter pi in gnuplot not rendering

Tags: utf-8, gnuplot, org-mode

I've got this code in an Emacs orgmode file:

```
#+begin_src gnuplot :exports results :file images/sinecosine.png
reset
set terminal png  size 360, 360 enhanced
# Line styles
set border linewidth 1
set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#0060ad' linetype 1 linewidth 1  # blue
set style line 2 linecolor rgb '#dd181f' linetype 1 linewidth 1  # red
# Legend
set key at 6.1,1.3
# Axes label 
set xlabel 'x'
set ylabel 'y'

set xzeroaxis linetype 2 linewidth 1
  set yzeroaxis linetype 2 linewidth 1
# Axis ranges
set xrange[-2*pi:2*pi]
set yrange[-1.5:1.5]
# Axis labels
set xtics ("-2{/Symbol P}" -2*pi, "-{/Symbol P}" -pi, 0, "{/Symbol P}" pi, "2{/Symbol P}" 2*pi)
set ytics 1
set tics scale 0.75


# Functions to plot
a = 0.9
f(x) = a * sin(x)
g(x) = a * cos(x)
# Plot
plot f(x) title 'sin(x)' with lines ls 1, \
     g(x) notitle with lines ls 2


#+end_src
```

and it gives a gnuplot (3.7) without the proper pi symbol -- just like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824152/how-to-show-%CF%80-symbol-on-x-axis) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648086/how-do-i-include-greek-letter-in-gnuplot) post. Yes, I can get the eps version of this to work, but not this png (or svg) version, which is needed for HTML export. Any new ideas?

**Update**

Here is the stand-alone code I've tried -- successfully:

```
reset
set encoding utf8
set terminal svg enhanced fname 'Times New Roman' rounded dashed standalone
set output "gp-test4-output.svg"

# Line styles
set border linewidth 1
set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#0060ad' linetype 1 linewidth 1  # blue
set style line 2 linecolor rgb '#dd181f' linetype 1 linewidth 1  # red
# Legend
set key at 6.1,1.3
# Axes label 
set xlabel 'x'
set ylabel 'y'

set xzeroaxis linetype 2 linewidth 1
  set yzeroaxis linetype 2 linewidth 1
# Axis ranges
set xrange[-2*pi:2*pi]
set yrange[-1.5:1.5]
# Axis labels
set xtics ("-2Π" -2*pi, "-Π" -pi, 0, "Π" pi, "2Π" 2*pi)
set ytics 1
set tics scale 0.75


# Functions to plot
a = 0.9
f(x) = a * sin(x)
g(x) = a * cos(x)
# Plot
plot f(x) title 'sin(x)' with lines ls 1, \
     g(x) notitle with lines ls 2
```

I've swapped out the `{/Symbol P}` for Π. From a terminal command line I've gotten it to work and produce just fine. The Ubuntu repo did install the latest-greatest gnuplot (gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 6). So doing the experiment again, when I `C-c C-c` in the org-mode codeblock I get

```
gnuplot-mode 0.7-beta (gnuplot 3.7) -- report bugs with "C-c C-u"
```

and the same error: junk instead of Π. (Not sure what the gnuplot 3.7 is about.) Running the codeblock above, BTW, starts a gnuplot REPL, and it says it's latest-greatest gnuplot. But when the stand-alone code above in Emacs (with gnuplot-mode) is called a la "send buffer to gnuplot" (the Emacs gnuplot REPL) it gives the error, BUT when I "send **file** to gnuplot", it produces the Π error-free. Totally bizarre, IMHO.

Here's my subscriptions:

```
(setq package-archives '(("ELPA"  . "http://tromey.com/elpa/")
             ("gnu"   . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
             ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
             ("org"   . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")))
```

which gives two offerings for gnuplot modes:

```
gnuplot            20141231.2137 available  melpa      drive gnuplot from within emacs
```

and then this:

```
gnuplot-mode       20171013.1616 installed             Major mode for editing gnuplot scripts
```

So then I uninstalled Emacs `gnuplot` (20141231.2137), then installed `gnuplot-mode`(20171013.1616). This solved the `gnuplot-run-buffer` problem, but the org-mode codeblock now gives this error:

```
executing Gnuplot code block...
org-babel-execute:gnuplot: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, gnuplot
```

Searching `customize` I only find four variables associated with gnuplot, one being Gnuplot Program, which I have as `/usr/bin/gnuplot`. I'm on latest-greatest Emacs and org-mode in Ubuntu 19.04. How do I better tell org-babel where to find Gnuplot? I suspect this newer mode is not the intended partner for Emacs org-mode; however the older mode is not doing greek letters properly in org-mode.

Comment: Have you tried `set term pngcairo enhanced`? Which version of gnuplot are you using? gnuplot 3.7?

Comment: At this point I'd like to stick with `set terminal svg enhanced...` I'm on 3.7.

Comment: why do you use gnuplot 3.7 and having problems with π instead of updating, e.g. to 5.2.6?

Comment: Good question. Right. I just took what Ubuntu gave me. Time to upgrade. I'll do that now and get back to us....

Comment: Okay, see my Update. New weirdness. . . .

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving the character "pi" from the Adobe Symbol font is something from the PostScript world, where separate fonts with special encodings were used to work around the 256-character limit inherent in PostScript font encodings.

SVG, on the other hand, is an XML variant.  It uses unicode entry points and (usually) UTF-8 encoding to access them.  "pi" in an SVG file is either the byte sequence 0xCF 0x80  (UTF-8 encoding) or the XML predefined entity `&#960;` .
gnuplot's "enhanced text" mode is not relevant here. I do not remember what limitations there might have been in gnuplot 3.7 that would affect passing either of these as normal text to the svg terminal.  There are no such limitations in current gnuplot.

Comment: Yes, see my Update. Not at all sure what 3.7 is doing in the loop when the gnuplot Emacs starts is latest-greatest. . .