# How to get greek letter beta in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I need to insert greek letter Beta into YLabel of my plot. I am using `ubuntu` version `18.04` and `gnuplot` version `5.2`.
Based on the suggestions provided in [How do I include greek letter in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648086/how-do-i-include-greek-letter-in-gnuplot), I tried the following commands.
`set encoding iso_8859_1`
`set terminal jpeg large font 'arial,20' size 800,750`
`set termoption enhanced`
`set xlabel "{/=24 {/Arial:Bold S195/CB-H57/CB distance} ({\305})}"`
`set ylabel "{/=24 {/Arial:Bold D102/CB-H57/C{/Symbol b} distance} ({\305})}" enhanced`
But I am not getting Beta symbol in the output file. Instead blank empty rectangle is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic answer to any question "How do I use character <whatever> in gnuplot?" is `set encoding utf8`.  See the [FAQ](http://gnuplot.info/faq/index.html).

In particular:

1. Do not use PostScript constructs like `{/Symbol b}` or `{\305}` if you are not creating PostScript output.  The special Adobe Symbol font is a PostScript-only work around from the 1980s.
2. You have explicitly set the encoding to iso-8859-1, which does not include any Greek letters.  Do not do that.

Your ylabel command should look like this:

```
set encoding utf8
... other commands ...
set ylabel "{/Arial:Bold=24 D102/CB-H57/Cβ distance (⊕)}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As per your suggestion, β is reflecting correctly in the plot. But ⊕ is not reflecting as Angstrom.

Comment: I am able to use the symbol Å directly and it is reflecting correctly in the plot. ```set ylabel "{/Arial:Bold=24 D102/CB-H57/Cβ distance (Å}"```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I looked up {\305} in the Adobe Symbol font and thought you were trying for that character.  Yeah Å is actually easier.  It was present even in your original encoding ISO-8859-1. There was no need for the escape sequence.